# How to override method of base class that haven't override in signature

Tags: c#, reflection, typebuilder

Today I discovered an interesting thing. I tried to define a type dynamically using `TypeBuilder` and tried to 'override' (i.e. replace) a method defined in the base class:

```
public class Test
{
    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test from Test");
    }
}

public void Bind(string methodToReplace, Action expr)
{
    @object = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    Type objectType = @object.GetType();
    AssemblyBuilder asmBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Mock"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    ModuleBuilder modBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("Mock");
    TypeBuilder tB = modBuilder.DefineType(objectType.Name, TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class, objectType);
    var mB = tB.DefineMethod(methodToReplace, MethodAttributes.Public);
    ILGenerator ilGen = mB.GetILGenerator();
    ilGen.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, expr.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke"), null);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    @object = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(tB.CreateType());
}
```

But, unfortunetly, in the defined type there are **two** methods with the same name 'Method', ('t' is an instance of the dynamically defined type):

```
t.GetType().GetMethods()
{System.Reflection.MethodInfo[6]}
    [0]: {Void Method()}
    [1]: {Void Method()}
    [2]: {System.String ToString()}
    [3]: {Boolean Equals(System.Object)}
    [4]: {Int32 GetHashCode()}
    [5]: {System.Type GetType()}
```

So my question is: how to add a new method that hides the base class's implementation, equivalent to using the C# 'new' keyword when defining  a new method, e.g.:

```
public class Test2 : Test
{
    new public void Method()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only override `virtual` methods.

Comment: @HenkHolterman coirius probably means C# method hiding.

Comment: Seems like MethodAttributes.HideBySig might have an effect here?

Comment: @EugenePodskal - might be, it's not all too clear. coinus: sloppy use of the word `override` .

Comment: @Corey I've tried MethodAttributes.HideBySign, but it don't work for me. I still have two methods with same name in type, and I cannot invoke any of them

Comment: Try using NewSlot as MethodAttribute. This question looks helpful to me for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335597/dynamically-create-subclass-which-overrides-virtual-final-methods

Answer (score 1):

You can see two methods because you used type.GetMethods() without bindingflags. Try to use bindingflags.declaredonly.

You can see only one method.
It is exactly what you want to to.

new keyword is a c# thing to avoid hiding base method by mistake.

it force you to use override or new to avoid warning.

if you want to override base merhod, use method DefineMethodOverride on TypeBuilder.